# Getting Innodb Lock Thread Id in MySQL 5.7?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to debug 'innodb lock waits' according to [this manual](https://severalnines.com/database-blog/how-fix-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-error-mysql). It suggests that I visualise debugging info using query

```
use performance_schema; 
SELECT THREAD_ID,EVENT_ID,EVENT_NAME,CURRENT_SCHEMA,SQL_TEXT FROM events_statements_history_long 
WHERE THREAD_ID IN (SELECT BLOCKING_THREAD_ID FROM data_lock_waits) ORDER BY EVENT_ID')
```

However `data_lock_waits` is present in MySQL > 5.7 while I have MySQL = 5.7. Tutorial suggests that I look into `information_schema.INNODB_LOCK_WAITS`. However, this table has the following columns: `requesting_trx_id requested_lock_id blocking_trx_id blocking_lock_id`.
How I can translate `blocking_trx_id` into Blocking Thread Id in MySQL 5.7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is this request:

```
SELECT
  r.trx_id waiting_trx_id,
  r.trx_mysql_thread_id waiting_thread,
  r.trx_query waiting_query,
  b.trx_id blocking_trx_id,
  b.trx_mysql_thread_id blocking_thread,
  b.trx_query blocking_query
FROM       information_schema.innodb_lock_waits w
INNER JOIN information_schema.innodb_trx b
  ON b.trx_id = w.blocking_trx_id
INNER JOIN information_schema.innodb_trx r
  ON r.trx_id = w.requesting_trx_id;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-information-schema-examples.html